# Why can we format text with bold and italic but not underline?

Tags: support, markdown

Why is it that *italic* and **bold** formatting is available while underline is not?

I guess it is voluntary, I'm just wondering why that would be the case.

Comment: I've never missed the ability to underline stuff in two years.

Comment: Underlining has (still) connotations of a clickable hyperlink.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24142/ for previous discussion on this

Comment: In the **three** years that I have been on Stack Overflow, I never thought about using an underline. I have thought about using strikeout though.

Comment: For those who might wonder about tag removal: this is a support question asking "Why", so a status tag does not really fit.

Comment: Here's a post on [UX.SE] about whether there is ever a need for underlining text when it's not a link - http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18086/is-there-ever-a-requirement-to-allow-text-to-be-underlined-when-its-not-a-link

Comment: "I can't think of a legitimate use for this, therefore no one else has a legitimate use for it, either." — SE logic

Comment: `works <u>fine</u>`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Underlining as a typographic means of emphasis is a relic of typewriters and handwriting. I'm not saying these two are dead (at least not both of them), but underlining is far inferior to bolding (for emphasizing and having it **stand out** from the rest of the text) and italicizing (for emphasizing but leaving the text's gray value intact, thus *not* standing out).

Using underlining for emphasis is only for when you have no other way. And we certainly do.

In addition, [Juhana is right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117016/text-formatting-why-bold-and-italic-but-not-underline#comment-306417); on the web, underlining means "clickable".

Comment: *Because* **bolding** *and* **putting** *everything* **in** *italics* **makes** *everything* **look** *better*.

Comment: On a side note: our very own UX.SE has an [interesting question on allowing underline](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/18086/7242).

Comment: **Bold** is better than u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲e̲.

Comment: For me hyperlinks on a web were always distinguishable by color difference and not by underlining. On the other hand, I was never used to using **bold** for emphasis, because for me its purpose is for headers and it attracts *too much* attention compared to u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲i̲n̲g̲. U̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲i̲n̲g̲ is something in between **bold** and *italic*.

Comment: Underlines damage legibility of letters with descenders (çgjpqy). @casperOne, are you one of those vandals who underline whole paragraphs of a book?

Comment: @EvgenKo423, to my eye, your underlines here stand out much more than the alternatives.

Comment: I use italics for emphasis, and bold for important things. Underlines have no added semantic value in the context of Markdown on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 39):

You can u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲e̲ t̲e̲x̲t̲ by using the unicode combining character `U+0332`:

```
u&#x332;n&#x332;d&#x332;e&#x332;r&#x332;l&#x332;i&#x332;n&#x332;e&#x332;d&#x332;
```

Use this bookmarklet to underline the selected text in the active input control:

```js
javascript:(function(){var el=document.activeElement,$el=$(el),start=el.selectionStart,end=el.selectionEnd,val=$el.val(),text=val.substring(start,end).replace(/\S/g,"$&\u0332");$el.val(val.substring(0,start)+text+val.substring(end));el.selectionStart=start;el.selectionEnd=start+text.length})();void 0;
```

Comment: Looks [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xXw1u.png) on Chrome 16, Ubuntu 11.10. Yuck!

Comment: Well, ya..  Not great, but perhaps better than nothing.  On WP7 the line is solid at least, but offset by half a character to the right. I'd post a screenshot, but WP7 still lacks that capability.

Comment: +1 for being very evil with your use of what is available.

Comment: For spacing, use `&nbsp;` instead of normal spaces. Trying to combine normal spaces with `&#x332;` will give you odd and ugly results.

Comment: Sometimes nothing is better than something.

Comment: Removed implicit jquery dependency from bookmarklet `javascript:(function() {     var el = document.activeElement;          var start = el.selectionStart;     var end = el.selectionEnd;      var val = el.value;      var text = val.substring(start, end).replace(/\S/g, "$&\u0332");      el.value = val.substring(0, start) + text + val.substring(end);      el.selectionStart = start;     el.selectionEnd = start + text.length; })();`

Answer (score 30):

On the web, an underline denotes a clickable link.

We do not and should not encourage contributors to create confusion by underlining regular text.

Comment: Very few of the links on SO are underlined.  I'm not sure this would create *legitimate* confusion.

Comment: @Charles: That's a design choice - one that many might disagree with but that's beside the point. The underline indicates a hyperlink, period; it doesn't matter whether or not the *real* hyperlinks are underlined, underlined text on the site is going to signal to readers that there is a hyperlink when there actually isn't.

Answer (score -2):

t͟e͟s͟t͟i͟n͟g͟ ͟i͟f͟ ͟t͟o͟o͟l͟s͟ ͟w͟o͟r͟k͟s͟

Nice!

So this is the tool: https://yaytext.com/underline/

Just enter the text there, copy the underlined text, and paste it in stackoverflow:

[image: screenshot of the tool]

If the previous tool is removed in the future, what I did to found it is searching on Google:

> underline characters online