# Underline and color picker

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Having font color option in SO question Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115455/having-font-color-option-in-so-question-editor)
>   [Why can we format text with bold and italic but not underline?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117016/why-can-we-format-text-with-bold-and-italic-but-sideline-the-underline)

A feature request:

I would like to have an "**underline**" button in the edit window. Because I am asked to explain why I want this feature: I think this can be handy to layout and structure your question in a better way.

If this leads to confusion with hyperlinks, a solution would be to colour and tooltip hyperlinks.

A simple **color picker** would be very nice, too, also for layout reasons.

Comment: A color picker? For what? Btw, you might want to clearly formulate this as a stand-alone feature request. Starting off with "and another feature request" indicates that this is some sort of run-on feature request? Include all necessary info here. I don't want to have to go through previous requests to get the background.

Comment: Thanks for that minor edit, but still, could you clarify why you make these requests? What do you need this functionality for? How will it improve the site?

Comment: I'm sorry, but "for layout reasons" does not do it for me. It seems to me you want to add a lot of unnecessary emphasis to certain parts of your questions/answers. And I'm not even thinking about the potential "abuse" of the use of coloring. I hate to see posts appear which look like a clown vomited over them. Even your current use of bold is not necessary in my opinion. But like I said, just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, Bart. I think if you hate layout, colours etc., why don´t you ban bold and italic from the edit window too? I can assure you that this can lead to absolutely disgusting effects. But maybe, you have not the power to remove these features... ;) By the way, which reasons other than layout could there be here? Does every feature you´d like to see need to have some "functionality"?

Comment: I do indeed think that the other formatting options are often abused as well. But not much I can do about those besides editing the content. And yes, every feature does need a purpose. It does need to somehow improve the site or solve a particular problem. If it doesn't, then why should the developers spend their precious time on it? Improved layout might be a reason, but then you have to demonstrate where we fall short at the moment, and how your new layout tools address that. This includes considering potential abuse of/problems with what you propose. Just saying "I want this" doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, Bart, isn´t that the problem with freedom itself? It is so often abused... The more possibilities people get, the more they tend to misbehave. Perhaps I will put forward a feature request to ban bold and italic. It should be successful, shouldn´t it? These feature don´t solve any problems and can lead to badly designed questions.

Comment: You can try. I don't give you a whole lot of chance of getting that through though.

Comment: See also [Is there ever a requirement to allow text to be underlined when it's not a link or a header](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/18086/7627)

Answer (score 5):

Underline can get confused with a link - which are the only source of underlines on StackOverflow right now. This could make users think that your underlined portion of text were a link instead of emphasized - of which there is already bold, italics, caps, and code styling.