# Remove bold and italic from ask question window

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

I would like the bold and italic button to be removed from the ask question window.

**The** *reason* is, that *these* **features** can **easily** be abused by *unexperienced*, amateur *users* **lacking** the knowledge of how to **layout** texts *correctly*.

This is subject of concern to many of the better, more experienced SO users. As for evidence, look here:

[SO feature request concerning colors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115455/having-font-color-option-in-so-question-editor)

Here, a feature request for adding a color picker got a voting of -14. Some user writes:

> Having colors would enable people to abuse them.

and gives some very nice of example of how colors can destroy the visual appearance of a text.

The same user does not seem to object bold and italics, possibly because the abuse of these features does not happen that often (as another user writes). But as to my own question, linked here - [My feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152160/underline-and-color-picker) - a user clearly dislikes my use of bold in the question text (only used at two wimpy places), and after giving it some thought I think he is absolutely right.

From this evidence it gets clear: 
text emphasizes peril the visual appearance of texts as much as colours, even if used moderately. How many ugly looking questions may there float around in SO, hurting the eye?

Secondly: stupid users prevented from using their beloved Facebook colors will the more be tempted to use emphasizes as a mean of expressing their (very mediocre) thoughts.

So, the danger of low level users abusing things like text emphasizes must be removed - stop things getting wrong right from the start.

Comment: Everything can be abused. What about lists? Hyperlinks? What you actually suggest is to let new users have only plain text. Better let them make mistakes then point it out to them and have them learn.

Comment: *"stupid users prevented from using their beloved Facebook colors will the more be tempted to use emphasizes as a mean of expressing their (very mediocre) thoughts."*...you might want to strike a somewhat different tone.

Comment: Bart, I thought at least you would defend me...

Comment: I will never ever defend anyone calling users stupid or their thoughts mediocre. No matter my views on the abuse of bold or italics.

Comment: Well, there you are. You are not wrong. At least I can say I haven´t insulted anyone personally.

Comment: **News flash:** `people` are `upset` that `other people` are `abusing` *formatting*.

Comment: is `this` *a* **joke**?

Comment: @prusswan _if_ it **is**, then `it's a bad` one.

Answer (score 7):

## `MANY` TYPES `of` formatting `ABUSE` CAN `be` far `WORSE` THAN `bold` and `ITALIC` TEXT.

Comment: This one is at least uniform, pick a better example!

Comment: @prusswan: Better?

Comment: ¡ʍou ɹǝʇʇǝq ɥɔnɯ

Answer (score 6):

wHô ÑêΣD$ ╒δΓma┬┬îñg tö bé äßú$î√ê ªπD ä∩Ñºÿi∩G?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't such a good idea. While I agree with you that abusing formatting is somewhat common (`any formatting`, not just *bold* and **italic**) removing a useful feature that most people use correctly would be counterproductive.

Your request for a color picker wasn't shot down just because it would be prone to abuse, the main reason is that neither you nor any of the people who previously asked similar features convinced the community that the feature would be actually useful. We can certainly live with a few people abusing an otherwise useful feature, but not with a feature that is both encouraging crappy formatting *and* isn't really useful to anyone.

Comment: Yannis, my request was closed, pointing to a similar request where as much as everyone disagreed because a color picker can be abused. But thanks for your information.

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald Hm? The [request you were pointed at](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115455/having-font-color-option-in-so-question-editor) also has [a highly upvoted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115456/162704) that argues there wouldn't be much use for such a feature. Abuse is a problem, but it's not the main problem, the main problem is that your feature would be largely useless.

Comment: I must agree with you that the requests lack really convincing arguments. Of course I could show concrete examples. But I still feel the fear abuse will be so dominant that all arguments have no real chance. However, I will keep this in mind for the next request.

Answer (score 2):

Emphasis is useful, making a sentence or a word bold can be effectively used to draw attention. It can of course be also misused, but that is no reason to completely remove it.

But we don't need even more different ways to emphasize, bold and italic should be enough. That is the reason for the negative reaction to the color picker. Adding an unnecessary option that can be abused is different than having a very useful option that can be abused.

Comment: +1 that is exactly my thought as well. I can think of no situation, other than syntax highlighting (which we do) where colour formatting would be necessary or would be an improvement over what is already in place.