# Underline text in Stack Overflow wiki editor

Tags: support, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can we format text with bold and italic but sideline the underline?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117016/why-can-we-format-text-with-bold-and-italic-but-sideline-the-underline)

How can I underline text in my questions in Stack Overflow??

This is important for me to format object text like in

```
my:House
```

in OOP.

This workaround looks a bit stupid at times but maybe it is worth considering. It uses `U+0332`—`COMBINING LOW LINE`—after each character to render it underlined

I could not combine a semicolon with an underline, so, these are the results.

```
t̲e̲x̲t̲
m̲y̲:H̲o̲u̲s̲e̲
 :̲
```

m̲y̲:̲H̲o̲u̲s̲e̲

m̲y̲:H̲o̲u̲s̲e̲

u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲e̲d̲ t̲e̲x̲t̲

u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲e̲d̲

**Reference:** [*Why can we format text with bold and italic but not underline?*](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117016/why-can-we-format-text-with-bold-and-italic-but-sideline-the-underline)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Markdown doesn't have a defined syntax to underline text so to answer your question, you can't.

Comment: Not completely true, you can always use **ascii underline** - however *it looks a bit odd* when used on characters that have a part under the line (y,g,q,...) There are existing tools that will do this for you e.g. http://manytools.org/facebook-twitter/strikethrough-text/ example: `n̲i̲c̲e̲ t̲e̲x̲t̲,̲ u̲g̲l̲y̲O̲n̲e̲ y̲,̲g̲,̲q̲,̲.̲.̲.̲`

Comment: @jave.web That's actually awesome and better than nothing.

Comment: It doesn't have to be pure markdown.  There's also that subset of allowed HTML.  While deprecated, the admins _could_ allow `<u>`, much as they have for `<b>` and `<i>`.  But so far, they haven't, for reasons that remain obscure.

Comment: bookmarklet to underline selected text using UNICODE U+0332 `javascript:(function() {     var el = document.activeElement;          var start = el.selectionStart;     var end = el.selectionEnd;      var val = el.value;      var text = val.substring(start, end).replace(/\S/g, "$&\u0332");      el.value = val.substring(0, start) + text + val.substring(end);      el.selectionStart = start;     el.selectionEnd = start + text.length; })();`,